# Was Farore ever referred to as Fayore?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

Most people who've played Zelda games I'm sure are aware of the three goddesses in Hylian mythology: Din, Nayru and Farore. But when I was a kid I remember Farore being spelled Fayore. I thought that's how the name was spelled for years, but then I saw people spelling it Farore all over the place and figured I was just mistaken.

One day I was doing a Zelda related search and accidentally spelled her name Fayore, and noticed that I wasn't the only one who had thought it was spelled with a Y. For example, [there's this thread on a message board, but no one can find any sources that spell it fayore](http://www.zeldauniverse.net/forums/nes-snes-n64-zelda/126346-when-did-fayore-become-farore.html), and if you do a google search for Fayore there are a ton of other one off matches. It seems like a lot of people at one point or another have misspelled the name as Fayore.

That's a little too coincidental for me to think it's just poor spelling or poor memory on everyone's part. Is there any place in any of the Zelda games (Most likely OoT) that actually refer to Farore as Fayore? I figure there has to be, somewhere, in some version of one of the games. I can't seem to find any actual references to the name Fayore.

Comment: I played OoT through a few times and only remember seeing "Farore".

Comment: Most of the web searches do commonly refer to "1st edition". Not sure how much that'll figure in, but I suppose the best way to go about it would be to hopefully find someone who actually has such a copy.

Comment: I've never seen "Fayore" in any of the games, including OoT, and according to [Zelda Wiki](http://www.zeldawiki.org/Farore_(Goddess)), her name was first mentioned in the LttP manual anyway. Perhaps there might have been a typo in an early version of OoT (someone with a US gold cart would have to verify if it made it to the final release), but even if that's the case, it's nothing more than a typo.

Comment: In my experience, it has always been "Farore" though I _know_ in my mind, I read it "Fayore" all the time.

Comment: I'm aware it's probably just a typo, but I'm still interested in figuring out where the typo occurs. Just out of curiosity, and also to justify to myself that I'm not crazy.

Comment: ...and I'm the guy who just sees low-level tertiary names and ignores them.  Hee hee... if I can find a rom of the original N64 version (I own the cart so it's not stealing :P ), I'll see if I can hack into it and find a typo in the code.

Comment: To be sure, Fa[r]yore first appeared in OoT, correct?

Comment: I thought so, but as someone else noted, the name is also mentioned in the LttP owners manual. However, I never owned the original LttP on the SNES, so if I saw a reference to Fayore it was definitely in OoT. I was hoping someone would know, but it looks like I might have to pull out my N64 and play through the game and see what I can find myself. If the typo is there, it's definitely on my version of the cartridge.

Comment: Does anyone know Japanese?  Apparently "フロルの風" is "Farore's Wind", perhaps in Japanese it sounds like "Fayore"?

Comment: I know the japanese alphabet (not kanji though), and that reads "Farore no <kanji>". Assuming that the kanji is wind, that means exactly what you think it would: Farore's wind.

Comment: I definitely recall it being Fayore. I've played OoT several times over the years (most recent being about two years ago) and I don't recall ever seeing it as Farore. Original (partial and piecemeal) playthroughs were on a US cartridge, purchased by my neighbor right after the game was released. Later, complete playthrough was through emulation. My memory tells me it was Fayore in both, but I don't have proof...

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely always been Farore. I haven't been able to find any definitive proof that it was ever spelled Fayore in any game. If it's possible that you misread it, then any number of other people could have, as well. This just happens to be a pretty big coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

I actually thought that it was spelled "Fayore" as well. This thought, for myself, was revolving around the Ocarina of Time cartridge for N64 specifically and corrected elsewhere, presumably. That would lead me to think that if there was something leading multiple people toward this mispronunciation that it would be found there.

Answer (score 0):

I remember playing Link to the Past on GBA, and I'm pretty sure it was spelled Farore.

To be fair, they could very well have rewritten the name when porting from the SNES to GBA, but I highly doubt they would try to retcon her name like that.

Comment: I don't remember Farore being mentioned in Link to the Past on SNES at all.